# Add new service using laravel sail

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have a laravel 8 project created with composer. Then I added laravel sail by `composer require laravel/sail` and then executed command `php artisan sail:install`.
After `sail up` command, only `mysql` container was created and everything works well. But now I want to add `redis` to my docker container. How can I do this? I have no knowledge with Docker but laravel sail has made it very easy to use Docker. I want to add `redis` with the help of laravel sail. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can edit `docker-compose.yml`

In `services`:

```
laravel.test:
    ...
    depends_on:
        - mysql
        - redis
...
```

```
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
```

then finally, in `volumes`:

```
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

You can also start a fresh new project with

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis" | bash
```

then refer the generated `docker-compose.yml`

after you edit, save it then run `./vendor/bin/sail build` then only `sail up -d`

Comment: The command `php artisan sail:add service` now also works. So `php artisan sail:add redis` for Redis if not installed earlier.

Answer (score 12):

You can just issue the command `php artisan sail:install` again

Now select the services you need and separate them with `,`

So for example `0, 3, 7`
This will update your `docker-compose.yml` file and add the lines for `MySQL, Redis, Mailhog`. It might overwrite some of your old settings though!

Once you start sail again it will pull the services and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best solution but I think it's so easy.
Update your `docker-compose.yml` file using following lines:

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

just run the command `php artisan sail:add <service>`